# Error in ANOVA Type

Tags: r, error-handling, regression, linear-regression, anova

I tried to do ANOVA with my data. I want to check if there is an interaction effect between two factors. I use the code:

```
anova_3<- anova(lm(response ~ Fac_A * Fac_B, data,  type=3))
```

But I got an error

> In `lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)` :
>    extra argument ‘type’ will be disregarded

No matter what type I tried, always got the same answer and the same error. There are no `NA`s in my data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For code debugging please always ask with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description, with the desired output.

Comment: Was it a warning or an error? It's just telling you that `type` isn't an argument that `lm` uses, so it ignores it. If you're trying to specify what type of sum of squares to use, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20452/how-to-interpret-type-i-type-ii-and-type-iii-anova-and-manova/20455#20455) on `crossvalidated`.

Comment: Use the `Anova` function of the `car` package.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
library(car)
anova_3 <- Anova(lm(response ~ Fac_A * Fac_B, data),  type=3).
```

I found this link very useful:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-June/315986.html

Hope it helps.